# Deleting a single row in Core Data not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am trying to make a journaling application and I am working on deleting entries from Core Data. When I try to delete an object nothing happens, no error message, nothing, and the entry is still there and not deleted. Code:

```
- (void)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton *) button {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    NSLog(@"%i", button.tag);

    UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *secondViewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [secondViewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *thirdViewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [thirdViewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *fourthViewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [fourthViewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    JournalrAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entrys" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    matches = objects[1];
    [context deleteObject:matches];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but all four views that you are calling removeFromSuperview on are the same. What is the point of that?

Comment: Have you checked what it returns in the fetch request. Does it actually return the object you want to delete?

Comment: @Abizern I have uiimage for the uilabel background, the uilabel for the entry, a date uilabel and a unbutton to delete an entry

Comment: @ophychius what would be the best way to do that

Comment: @user2489946 But you are getting each view with the same call `[self.view viewWithTag:button.tag]` which returns the same object.

Comment: @user2489946 Try putting a breakpoint after 'matches = objects[1];' and check if it is still nil, and if not, try to see what is in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because of this line:

```
matches = objects[1];
```

Arrays are zero-indexed. So maybe you were looking for the first element (`objects[0]`)?
Do some NSLogs to see if there is actually something to delete.

Also, if you expect some kind of visual update in your views, don't. You must manually update your views to reflect the change in the database.